# How to debug django, it spawns a new process to which I'm not attached?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to debug django using PyCharm, and notice that it spawns a new process to which PyCharm is not attached. My breakpoints aren't hit in this new process.

How do I debug it then? (See `autoreload.restart_with_reloader()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are debugging - it is a good idea to have "--noreload" option for the dev-server.

AFAIK PyCharm has a checkbox "No reload" in the run options for the project.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't using PyCharm's Django integration at all, simply running manage.py as a python program. Once I selected the django run configuration, it worked like a charm - thanks.